# how to change timespan variable to a integer type?

Tags: c#, casting, timer, datepicker, dynamic-data

I'm trying to convert timespan variable into an integer variable using 'parse'. I get an error that says:

> Format exception was unhandled: Input string was not in correct format

This is the code is have :

```
   private void dateTimePicker4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan t = dateTimePicker4.Value.ToLocalTime() - dateTimePicker3.Value.ToLocalTime();
        int x = int.Parse(t.ToString());
        y = x;
    }
```

My target is to display this the change in time for two timepickers, dynamically in a text box, i.e, the difference in minutes between them should be displayed in a textbox automatically.

Comment: This in an awful question. Not the question itself, just that you are trying to parse the `ToString` value. You need to get in the habit of looking for existing properties and methods that might already do what you want. More often that not, the functionality usually exists already, somewhere

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> the difference in minutes between them should be displayed in a
>   textbox automatically.

Instead of parsing use [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) property.

```
t.TotalMinutes;
```

The property is of double type, if you just need to integer part then you can do:

```
int x = (int) t.totalMinutes;
```

Comment: what if the difference is bigger than an Int32 eg: diff. between start of time and now?

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana, use `long`. The point was to take the integer part of the number ...

Answer (score 4):

```
 private void dateTimePicker4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan t = dateTimePicker4.Value.ToLocalTime() - dateTimePicker3.Value.ToLocalTime();
        int x = int.Parse(t.Minutes.ToString());
        y = x;
    }
```

Have you tried changing it to `int x = int.Parse(t.Minutes.ToString());`?

From : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx